# How can I update the interanl test in google-playstore?

Tags: android, react-native, flutter, kotlin, google-play

I am using react-native and testing by using internal test.

However, there is a change in the code and I want to update it.

After running /android gradlew app:assembleRelease --stacktrace, upload 4 new apk files and upgrade the version again, but the code changes are not reflected.
The change in the code is not reflected even if the app is downloaded after deleting the app on the device.
How can I update it?

Comment: try to clean gradle before release build

Comment: @nazmul it's the same... i have to update twice if i do twice it reflect.. what is the problem??

Comment: Before you build, go to your `app/build.gradle` then change the number of `versionCode` to the value which larger than your current `versionCode`.